# Change group resources order in Kendo UI Scheduler

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

I have a Kendo UI Scheduler that shows a timeline as a view. What I want to do is to change the group resource order but I'm not able to do that. What I have tried is to change the order of the resources in the group configuration option, but even if I change the order the UI is still the same. It seems that the grouping order is computed starting from the `resources` property and not `group.resources`.

Here it is the base case which is taken from the Kendo UI demos:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/timeline">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.504/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.504/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.504/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.504/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.504/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.504/js/kendo.timezones.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="example" class="k-content">
    <div id="scheduler"></div>
</div>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
            date: new Date("2013/6/13"),
            startTime: new Date("2013/6/13 07:00 AM"),
            eventHeight: 50,
            majorTick: 60,
            views: [
                "timeline",
            ],
            timezone: "Etc/UTC",
            dataSource: {
                batch: true,
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/meetings",
                        dataType: "jsonp"
                    },
                    update: {
                        url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/meetings/update",
                        dataType: "jsonp"
                    },
                    create: {
                        url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/meetings/create",
                        dataType: "jsonp"
                    },
                    destroy: {
                        url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/meetings/destroy",
                        dataType: "jsonp"
                    },
                    parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                        if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                            return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                        }
                    }
                },
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "meetingID",
                        fields: {
                            meetingID: { from: "MeetingID", type: "number" },
                            title: { from: "Title", defaultValue: "No title", validation: { required: true } },
                            start: { type: "date", from: "Start" },
                            end: { type: "date", from: "End" },
                            startTimezone: { from: "StartTimezone" },
                            endTimezone: { from: "EndTimezone" },
                            description: { from: "Description" },
                            recurrenceId: { from: "RecurrenceID" },
                            recurrenceRule: { from: "RecurrenceRule" },
                            recurrenceException: { from: "RecurrenceException" },
                            roomId: { from: "RoomID", nullable: true },
                            attendees: { from: "Attendees", nullable: true },
                            isAllDay: { type: "boolean", from: "IsAllDay" }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            group: {
                resources: ["Rooms", "Attendees"],
                orientation: "vertical"
            },
            resources: [
                {
                    field: "roomId",
                    name: "Rooms",
                    dataSource: [
                        { text: "Meeting Room 101", value: 1, color: "#6eb3fa" },
                        { text: "Meeting Room 201", value: 2, color: "#f58a8a" }
                    ],
                    title: "Room"
                },
                {
                    field: "attendees",
                    name: "Attendees",
                    dataSource: [
                        { text: "Alex", value: 1, color: "#f8a398" },
                        { text: "Bob", value: 2, color: "#51a0ed" },
                        { text: "Charlie", value: 3, color: "#56ca85" }
                    ],
                    multiple: true,
                    title: "Attendees"
                }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

In the example below I change the order of the `group.resources` array property from `["Rooms", "Attendees"]` to `["Attendees", "Rooms"]`expecting a change in the grouping order in the UI, but nothing seems to happen:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/timeline">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.504/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.504/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.504/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.504/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.504/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.504/js/kendo.timezones.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="example" class="k-content">
    <div id="scheduler"></div>
</div>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
            date: new Date("2013/6/13"),
            startTime: new Date("2013/6/13 07:00 AM"),
            eventHeight: 50,
            majorTick: 60,
            views: [
                "timeline"
            ],
            timezone: "Etc/UTC",
            dataSource: {
                batch: true,
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/meetings",
                        dataType: "jsonp"
                    },
                    update: {
                        url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/meetings/update",
                        dataType: "jsonp"
                    },
                    create: {
                        url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/meetings/create",
                        dataType: "jsonp"
                    },
                    destroy: {
                        url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/meetings/destroy",
                        dataType: "jsonp"
                    },
                    parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                        if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                            return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                        }
                    }
                },
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "meetingID",
                        fields: {
                            meetingID: { from: "MeetingID", type: "number" },
                            title: { from: "Title", defaultValue: "No title", validation: { required: true } },
                            start: { type: "date", from: "Start" },
                            end: { type: "date", from: "End" },
                            startTimezone: { from: "StartTimezone" },
                            endTimezone: { from: "EndTimezone" },
                            description: { from: "Description" },
                            recurrenceId: { from: "RecurrenceID" },
                            recurrenceRule: { from: "RecurrenceRule" },
                            recurrenceException: { from: "RecurrenceException" },
                            roomId: { from: "RoomID", nullable: true },
                            attendees: { from: "Attendees", nullable: true },
                            isAllDay: { type: "boolean", from: "IsAllDay" }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            group: {
                resources: ["Attendees", "Rooms"],
                orientation: "vertical"
            },
            resources: [
                {
                    field: "roomId",
                    name: "Rooms",
                    dataSource: [
                        { text: "Meeting Room 101", value: 1, color: "#6eb3fa" },
                        { text: "Meeting Room 201", value: 2, color: "#f58a8a" }
                    ],
                    title: "Room"
                },
                {
                    field: "attendees",
                    name: "Attendees",
                    dataSource: [
                        { text: "Alex", value: 1, color: "#f8a398" },
                        { text: "Bob", value: 2, color: "#51a0ed" },
                        { text: "Charlie", value: 3, color: "#56ca85" }
                    ],
                    multiple: true,
                    title: "Attendees"
                }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

If I change also the `resources` property order the change happens as expected:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/timeline">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.504/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.504/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.504/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css" />

    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.504/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.504/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.2.504/js/kendo.timezones.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="example" class="k-content">
    <div id="scheduler"></div>
</div>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
            date: new Date("2013/6/13"),
            startTime: new Date("2013/6/13 07:00 AM"),
            eventHeight: 50,
            majorTick: 60,
            views: [
                "timeline"
            ],
            timezone: "Etc/UTC",
            dataSource: {
                batch: true,
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/meetings",
                        dataType: "jsonp"
                    },
                    update: {
                        url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/meetings/update",
                        dataType: "jsonp"
                    },
                    create: {
                        url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/meetings/create",
                        dataType: "jsonp"
                    },
                    destroy: {
                        url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/meetings/destroy",
                        dataType: "jsonp"
                    },
                    parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                        if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                            return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                        }
                    }
                },
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "meetingID",
                        fields: {
                            meetingID: { from: "MeetingID", type: "number" },
                            title: { from: "Title", defaultValue: "No title", validation: { required: true } },
                            start: { type: "date", from: "Start" },
                            end: { type: "date", from: "End" },
                            startTimezone: { from: "StartTimezone" },
                            endTimezone: { from: "EndTimezone" },
                            description: { from: "Description" },
                            recurrenceId: { from: "RecurrenceID" },
                            recurrenceRule: { from: "RecurrenceRule" },
                            recurrenceException: { from: "RecurrenceException" },
                            roomId: { from: "RoomID", nullable: true },
                            attendees: { from: "Attendees", nullable: true },
                            isAllDay: { type: "boolean", from: "IsAllDay" }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            group: {
                resources: ["Attendees", "Rooms"],
                orientation: "vertical"
            },
            resources: [
                {
                    field: "attendees",
                    name: "Attendees",
                    dataSource: [
                        { text: "Alex", value: 1, color: "#f8a398" },
                        { text: "Bob", value: 2, color: "#51a0ed" },
                        { text: "Charlie", value: 3, color: "#56ca85" }
                    ],
                    multiple: true,
                    title: "Attendees"
                },
                {
                    field: "roomId",
                    name: "Rooms",
                    dataSource: [
                        { text: "Meeting Room 101", value: 1, color: "#6eb3fa" },
                        { text: "Meeting Room 201", value: 2, color: "#f58a8a" }
                    ],
                    title: "Room"
                }
            ]
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I achieve the same result dynamically? What I have already tried is to change the order of the `resources` and `group.resources` and assigning them again to the scheduler by doing:

```
 var scheduler = $('#scheduler').data('kendoScheduler');
 // Omitted resources and groupingResources computation
 scheduler.setOptions({resources: resources});
 scheduler.setOptions({
    group: {
      orientation: 'vertical',
      resources: groupingResources
    }
  });
  scheduler.view(scheduler.view().name);
```

but I get the error

```
TypeError: d.dataSource.view is not a function
```

from the kendo.all.js file. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In such case we can update the resource collection, reset it and reload the view as for example it is done in this [dojo page](http://dojo.telerik.com/IdIlo). Here is the code that worked core me:

```
    var resourceData = scheduler.resources[0].dataSource.data();
    var first = resourceData.shift();

    resourceData.push(first);
    scheduler.resources[0].dataSource.data(resourceData);

    scheduler.view(scheduler.view().name);
```

Comment: What I want is not just simply add or remove items from a resource dataSource, but I also want to add new items to the resources array

Comment: Modifying the scheduler group resources after it's initialization is not supported out of the box. I would suggest to [destroy](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler#methods-destroy) the widget and re-initialize it with the new resources.